# Как циклом вывести статьи?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, json, api

У меня есть JSON что приходит по API (Screen)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот код:

```
   fetch('https://mysite.com.ua/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(function(posts){

        console.log(posts);



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$.each обход объектов/массивов

```
.then(function(posts){
    $.each(posts, function(index, item) {
        var content = item.content.rendered; // Можно так же попробовать обернуть это в $(); если не сработает в таком варианте
        $("#content_outer").append(// Можете использовать prepend в зависимости от требований
            content
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: @Walfler как я могу витащить ссилку на картинку?

Comment: @Alex я собственно не вижу её в доступных свойствах объекта что пришёл вам по API или вытаскивать за счёт id материала через wp-json или настраивать API...

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
.then(res => res.json())
.then(posts => {
  for (let post of posts) {
    showPost(post);
  }
})
.catch(err => {
  // Или иной способ обработки ошибок
  throw err;
});
function showPost(post) {
  const postWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  postWrapper.innerHTML = (`
    <h2>${post.title}</h2>
    <p>${post.body}</p>
   `);
  // Нужно заменить на элемент для размещения постов
  // Можно вынести этот элемент в параметры функции
  document.body.append(postWrapper);
}
```